# Python time.gmtime() returning time that's 5 hours ahead of system time

Tags: python, time, timezone

I have been scouring the google machine and have come up with nothing to answer this. When making calls to:

```
time.gmtime()
```

This ends up returning a time, as the subject line says, 5 hours ahead of my system time. I cannot figure out what is going on. time.tzname() returns the proper timezone. Aside from setting python to a timezone 5 hours earlier than mine, is there any way to correct this error?

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried moving to London? I think that will solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for [`time.localtime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.localtime)? As docs say [`time.gmtime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.gmtime) returns time struct in UTC.

Answer (score 5):

`time.gmtime()` returns Greenwich Mean Time. This is five hours ahead of Eastern Standard Time, for example; taking into account daylight savings time, it's five hours ahead of Central Standard Time.